# Approaches to setting an application into Read-Only mode without impacting performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC single-page-app that I'd like to place into read-only mode while I perform staging<>production swaps.  My initial thought is that I would do something like this:

```
if (!dbContext.SystemSettings.First(s => s.Key == 'ReadOnly').Value){//write to db}
```

But this means that for every PUT/POST/DELETE, I have to add another call to the database, throwing precious milliseconds on top of an optimized query.  What approaches are there to setting read-only mode on an application without storing/checking that information on the database, if any?

Comment: Maybe `Web.config` value? Or the same DB setting but cached for `n` minutes?

Comment: Are you using IoC?  You could have the application inject readonly components if some condition is met, such as a config flag.

Comment: If you're using Windows Identity Foundation (part of .Net!), you could use claims to lock things down.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov - does this mean that when I set my app to readonly, I can simply modify the web.config without recycling IIS or redeploying?

Comment: Maybe using an `XML` file for storing system setting be better idea rather than using `web.config`. for example if you are using shared hosting, Plesk won't let you change web.config programmatically.

Comment: @RobVious, no, `web.config` change will recycle AppPool and restart it, so if you need to do it on fly, then web.config isn't a way for you. You still can save it in DB, and cache loaded value for 5-10-20 minutes depending on how fast application should react on enabling ReadOnly mode.